# ESP32 Elx400 - BLE server crashes when using DAC, ADC and BLE at the same time

Tags: microcontroller, esp32

When using the ESP32's ADC, DAC and BLE functionality, I get an ELx400  error code signifying the BLE server has crashed. ELx400 is unfortunately poorly documented, and an extensive Google has been fruitless.

Background:

- Using: DFRobot FireBeetle ESP32 IoT controller
- Using ADC1 - there shouldn't be an issue with BLE running at the same time - yet there is. Using driver/adc.h to call adc.
- Using "DacESP32.h" to call DAC.
- Using BLE notify example to notify.
- Problem is reproducible across multiple of the same boards.
- Changing something in sdkconfig was recommended, but sdkconfig doesn't seem to exist (even on github)
- Currently re-writing script to micropython but failing that I want to try a new board (keen to hear recommendations abouth this as well)

Has anyone come up against this problem? DAC + ADC + BLE seems like a pretty standard set up for ESP32 in my opinion.

All recommendations are hugely appreciated.

Comment: As you're not asking for recommendations anymore (other than the last sentence being "all recommendations are hugely appreciated", which i assume was just missed), I've voted to reopen this question. It takes a couple (I forget how many) votes before a question is reopened, so it might be a little bit.